# Nested Loop, VBS and Random Numbers

Tags: loops, random, vbscript, nested, imacros

I am writing some vbs code, and I want to be able to pass a random number for `WAIT SECONDS`, while looping through one of my CSV files, So far I have this

```
Dim rn
rn = 50 + cint(rnd()*11)
iret = iim1.iimSet("mynumber", Cstr(rn)) 

dim intLoop
intLoop = 1
Do Until intLoop = 28
   i = iim1.iimSET("line", CStr(intLoop))
   i = iim1.iimPLAY(mypath & "deletemelater2.iim")
   intLoop = intLoop + 1
Loop
```

What happens is this only creates one number for the first instance, then the next loops for intLoop receive no numbers, I believe this requires a nested loop but have no good idea on how to proceed, if someone can help that would be grateful!!,

I now have this,

```
Dim rn
rn = 50 + cint(rnd()*11)
iret = iim1.iimSet("line2", Cstr(rn)) 

dim intLoop, outLoop
intLoop = 1
outLoop = 1
Do Until intLoop = 28 AND outLoop = 28
   i = iim1.iimSET("line", CStr(intLoop))
   i = iim1.iimPLAY(mypath & "deletemelater2.iim")
   intLoop = intLoop + 1
   rn = iim1.iimSET("line2", CStr(rn))
   rn = iim1.iimPLAY(mypath & "deletemelater2.iim")
   outLoop = outLoop + 1
```

but it is still not working properly, can anyone advise me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: not sure I follow this correctly, but is this not a case of moving the random number section _inside_ the loop?

Comment: That's exactly right.  The random number is only being generated one time.  It needs to be generated on each iteration by moving code inside of the loop.

Comment: hi i now have this,                                               Dim rn
rn = 50 + cint(rnd()*11)
iret = iim1.iimSet("line2", Cstr(rn)) 

dim intLoop, outLoop
intLoop = 1
outLoop = 1
Do Until intLoop = 28 AND outLoop = 28
   i = iim1.iimSET("line", CStr(intLoop))
   i = iim1.iimPLAY(mypath & "deletemelater2.iim")
   intLoop = intLoop + 1
   rn = iim1.iimSET("line2", CStr(rn))
   rn = iim1.iimPLAY(mypath & "deletemelater2.iim")
   outLoop = outLoop + 1
Loop, but its still not working properly, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example probably doesn't work for two reasons.

1. You are using the same random number each time.
2. You are now calling iimPLAY twice as many times as before.

I would change your original code as follows:

```
Dim rn
dim intLoop

For intLoop = 1 to 27
   rn = 50 + cint(rnd()*11)
   iret = iim1.iimSet("mynumber", Cstr(rn)) 
   i = iim1.iimSET("line", CStr(intLoop))
   i = iim1.iimPLAY(mypath & "deletemelater2.iim")
Next
```